# OrientDB toJSON with fetchplan removed meta tag information from JSON

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1, orientdb2.2

I am new to OrientDb when I have run this query

```
select * from V_User
```

Then I will used toJSON() method. It will return the full json with with meta tag info also that is

```
"@type":"d",
"@rid":"#28:0",
"@version":1,
"@class":"V_User",
```

But when I am used the toJSON() with fetchplan i.e toJSON("fetchPlan:*:-1") then It will return the inner edge information but removed the metatag information i.e removed this

```
"@type":"d",
"@rid":"#28:0",
"@version":1,
"@class":"V_User"
```

Can any one help me how to get Relations edge data with meta tag with toJSON methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got after research

```
toJSON("rid,version,fetchPlan:*:-1")
```

Which will get all inner edge relation with meta data